# Double Colons in Org-Mode Tags in Agena

Tags: org-mode

A tag in my agenda view in org-mode appears with two colons (double colons) after it (`:symposium::`). All other tags appear with only one colon after them (`:admin:`). What is the cause/reason for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears that way when the tag is inherited from the parent. I suspect this is to distinguish between tags that are associated directly with the headline and those that are inherited from it's parents.

With this example

```
#    -*- mode: org -*-

* TODO This is a test of inherited                                    :test:
** TODO This gets a double colon
*** TODO This also gets the double colon
** TODO This gets a double colon and an extra tag                    :test2:
*** TODO This gets a double colon after the extra tag
```

I get this when creating a list of all todo items

```
Global list of TODO items of type: ALL
Available with `N r': (0)ALL (1)TODO (2)DONE
  test:       TODO This is a test of inherited                            :test:
  test:       TODO This gets a double colon                              :test::
  test:       TODO This also gets the double colon                       :test::
  test:       TODO This gets a double colon and an extra tag       :test::test2:
  test:       TODO This gets a double colon after the extra tag    :test:test2::
```